# Debug youtube data API? (rating)

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

I've copied and pasted the rating API code as presented here for JS.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate?hl=es&apix_params=%7B%22id%22%3A%22O8IvzIs1s5Y%22%2C%22rating%22%3A%22none%22%7D&apix=true

It worked some days ago, but now I can't make it work. Authentication seems to be happening, but then the rating part doesn't change the rating nor fails. I do not even get any of the 2 console.log messages.

I'm testing it from localhost:8000 (http) which is authorized in the API.

HTML related code is:

```
  <button type="submit" onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Authorize me!</button>
  <button type="submit" onclick="execute()" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Rate it!</button>
```

JS part is:

```
  <!-- From: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate?apix=true#try-it -->
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script>
    /**
     * Sample JavaScript code for youtube.videos.getRating
     * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
     * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
     */

    function authenticate() {
      return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
          .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner"})
          .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
                function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
    }
    function loadClient() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey("MY API KEY");
      return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
          .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
                function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
    }
    // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
    function execute() {
      console.log("Pasa")
      return gapi.client.youtube.videos.rate({
        "id": "VIDEOID to rate",
        "rating": "dislike"
      }).then(function(response) {
                  // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                  console.log("Response", response);
      }, function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
    }
    gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
      gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "<CLIENT ID>"});
    });
  </script>
```

NOTE: I've replaced credentials and videoid.

EDITED:

@Nik, testing in Firefox gives me this: TypeError: gapi.client.youtube is undefined
[Learn More]
home:286:7
execute
http://localhost:8000/home:286:7
onclick gapi is not initialized?

I'm narrowing this down. My buttons where in the header tag .... moving the buttons out of the header it works. Does anyone has an explanation for this. Do JS variables have a reduce scope related to HTML tags?

Comment: Can please add what's the error that you are getting?

Comment: More info: I tested in a plain page, no other JS code (Had recent bootstrap 5 and JQuery) and worked.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, a bunch of "issues" related to SameSite cookies I do not understand. Not sure if this is related.

Comment: I think there is an error, but just appears a then of a second and then disappears. Can see how to get it. Final otput in the console a a couple of: XHR finished loading GET lines

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not failing, it is rating the video but API is not sending any response. it is sending status `204` which means:

`The HTTP 204 No Content success status response code indicates that a request has succeeded, but that the client doesn't need to navigate away from its current page.`

Note: ID of the video should be correct

Comment: Thanks @Rahul! But I do not see the rating changing in the video. Must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to have bothered you @Rahul Arora, @Nik. Now I know what was wrong. Is nothing about HEADER tag.

My buttons where inside a FORM!:

```
<form>
<button type="submit" onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Authorize me!</button>
  <button type="submit" onclick="execute()" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Rate it!</button>
</form>
```

And the form was submitted, therefore, losing the gapi authenticated instance when execute was happening.

It's my fault! I adapted an HTML template without realizing the buttons where inside a form. I'm posting this in case someone else make this same stupid mistake!